# Binding generic value back to controller via post method

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't figure out how to bind back generic value from view when sending it back to controller via post method.

I have generic class PageModel that inherites from GenericModel. PageModel has additional parameter Page (class that have two int parameters, pageSize and pageNumber). GenericModel has only generic value of T named viewModel and nothing more. The problem is that standard C# binder binds Page parameter without any issues, but no matter what I'm trying to do ViewModel is never filled in.

Models:

```
public class GenericModel<T>
{
    public T ViewModel { get; set; }

    public GenericModel(T viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public GenericModel()
    {

    }
}

public class PageModel<T> : GenericModel<T>
{
    public Page Page { get; set; }

    public PageModel(T viewModel, Page page) : base(viewModel)
    {
        Page = page;
    }

    public PageModel() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

Generic Parameter:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public IList<string> NewRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(PageModel<UserModel> model)
    {
        var isUpdated = await _userServices.Update(model.ViewModel);

        ViewData["IsUpdated"] = isUpdated;

        return View("Index", await _userServices.GetUsersPage(model.Page.PageNumber, model.Page.PageSize));
    }
```

View:

```
@model PageModel<UserModel>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Update";
}

<h1>Update</h1>

<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Update" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ViewModel.Id"></label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Id" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ViewModel.Password"></label>
    <input type="password" asp-for="ViewModel.Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword"></label>
    <input type="password" asp-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ViewModel.Roles"></label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Roles" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Roles" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Page.PageNumber"></label>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Page.PageNumber" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Page.PageNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Page.PageSize"></label>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Page.PageSize" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Page.PageSize" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

@foreach (var availableRole in (IList<IdentityRole>)ViewData["AllRoles"])
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="newRoles" value="@availableRole.Name"
               checked="@Model.ViewModel.Roles.Contains(availableRole.Name)">
        <label class="form-check-label">@availableRole</label>
    </div>
}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
```

Do you know what can be the issue? Is naming convention wrong? I've already tried to find answer on stack, but with no luck.

**

### EDIT 1:

**

This is what is generated by ASP.NET (Copied from google chrome)

```
   <form method="post" action="/Admin/Update/439c61f5-d721-4e10-b49c-6263b7929c6a">
        <div class="text-danger validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
    </ul></div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.Id"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Id" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ViewModel_Password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 and at max 100 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" id="ViewModel_Password" name="ViewModel.Password">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ViewModel.Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ViewModel_ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ViewModel_ConfirmPassword" name="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ViewModel_Roles">Roles</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" id="ViewModel_Roles" name="ViewModel.Roles" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ViewModel.Roles" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Page_PageNumber">PageNumber</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PageNumber field is required." id="Page_PageNumber" name="Page.PageNumber" value="1">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Page.PageNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Page_PageSize">PageSize</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PageSize field is required." id="Page_PageSize" name="Page.PageSize" value="5">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Page.PageSize" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="newRoles" value="Administrator">
                <label class="form-check-label">Administrator</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="newRoles" value="User" checked="checked">
                <label class="form-check-label">User</label>
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8Hsh_QOxexZLjyWnCjnNzz2ZhIuA-aPvi2MKBsCF12vrc6FY2yJnWGo1Nq9xNtwuiq7dTKdt93hUTJUf0PDD8RX1CJGgo0Jc3eDJMf8Ymh13fz0K60_S-uajXL3lNZalJJ58idjvok61tqa6oddepoWN1A0BUYHsk-h-PdfUCswqBSrt9GsHdbRvS5NrIitiZQ"></form>

Form data from google dev tools:

    ViewModel.Password: 
    ViewModel.ConfirmPassword: 
    ViewModel.Roles: System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D
    Page.PageNumber: 1
    Page.PageSize: 5
    newRoles: User
    __RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8Hsh_QOxexZLjyWnCjnNzz2AyLo8vWEn4NIFS4brVjbJsYdFKgY97yj5IO8trooYDKkrdxPlFrGk2hmPQrmoEKgmGSno2jdOwGud-5Fcy8ewmp7K2pl1XODyKXxYSaZ3TngHSl1KLpMb9REpq4_Nqh45sdO1eBaMqpw3dfgCoAbvc6m2nEKJlDaRm_2eaKTX-w
```

Decoded form (the same as above):

```
ViewModel.Password=&ViewModel.ConfirmPassword=&ViewModel.Roles=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D&Page.PageNumber=1&Page.PageSize=5&newRoles=User&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8Hsh_QOxexZLjyWnCjnNzz2AyLo8vWEn4NIFS4brVjbJsYdFKgY97yj5IO8trooYDKkrdxPlFrGk2hmPQrmoEKgmGSno2jdOwGud-5Fcy8ewmp7K2pl1XODyKXxYSaZ3TngHSl1KLpMb9REpq4_Nqh45sdO1eBaMqpw3dfgCoAbvc6m2nEKJlDaRm_2eaKTX-w
```

**EDIT 2**

I've changed the disable tag from id to readonly, and now ID is being sent. I don't thing I've changed anything else but I think thanks to that every single other property is added, but IList with roles. There still is a problem. Roles don't bind at all.

```
ViewModel.Id: fde0b182-3b24-4d5b-b31e-3680b7cfd4de
ViewModel.Password: 19923845379
ViewModel.ConfirmPassword: 1284326898838
ViewModel.Roles: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
Page.PageNumber: 1
Page.PageSize: 5
newRoles: Administrator
newRoles: User
__RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8Hsh_QOxexZLjyWnCjnNzz1Hy5YNNny4vPyGFd434Uybuo-O-dMFHT7eSKvd7JKA_dqxlQDIFlNzVsSjTDT6lzl7d2AU6Pj1nVRUyux3OZ2cGbyyBVKZHUI0Kq4u_MAx_b_29SUVSYh5Tpayc-0WPdcjGfxKLvL1qrbn6qeHcNk356VsPG1AC5cphft3frjILA
```

**EDIT 3 [Solved]**

Thanks to @itminus help I could solve the issue. Below you have changed form with two versions of the same - Roles with

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Update" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.Id"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Id" readonly class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.Password"></label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="ViewModel.Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.ViewModel.Roles.Count(); i++) { 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.Roles[i]"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Roles[i]" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Roles[i]" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
         }
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" asp-for="Page.PageNumber" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Page.PageNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" asp-for="Page.PageSize" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Page.PageSize" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    @foreach (var availableRole in (IList<IdentityRole>)ViewData["AllRoles"])
    {
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ViewModel.NewRoles[]" value="@availableRole.Name"
                   checked="@Model.ViewModel.Roles.Contains(availableRole.Name)">
            <label class="form-check-label">@availableRole</label>
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
</form>
```

What is being sent from form now. (Example values)

```
ViewModel.Id: bf872461-f429-497f-8159-898e1dfafad9
ViewModel.Password: 1394657234609243070
ViewModel.ConfirmPassword: 2346-7345-67356667
ViewModel.Roles[0]: User
Page.PageNumber: 1
Page.PageSize: 5
ViewModel.NewRoles[]: Administrator
ViewModel.NewRoles[]: User
__RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8Hsh_QOxexZLjyWnCjnNzz1AvzPUt8DrSfqpOni-Q65jAFnRqNs875teRTned_OQ6S7GV19WwWRqE7yRgTNmeeX9Twg4RjgQR_JEibtFYpHN6zbDJgLeauyyHxwOukRSTl0GZIRii5VaQBUxIbK6A8qHxgl4bn5-01YLj8bOXV9Ze7TvdP3MTX7ghYcAprPUJQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is naming convention wrong?

Yes. The name convention is :

1. Dot (`.`) represents property
2. `[]` represents collection index or dictionary

However, in your previous code, `NewRoles` fields have the name of `newRoles`:

```
<input ... name="newRoles"  ...>
```

which is not correct. The same goes for the `Roles` property.

So you need change you code in following way:

1. `Roles`:

   ```
   <label asp-for="ViewModel.Roles"></label>
   <input type="text" asp-for="ViewModel.Roles" class="form-control" hidden="hidden" />
   <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Roles" class="text-danger"></span>
   @for(var i=0; i < Model.ViewModel.Roles.Count(); i++)
   {
       <input type="hidden" name="ViewModel.Roles[]" value="@Model.ViewModel.Roles[i]" />
   }
   ```
2. `NewRoles`:

   ```
   @foreach (var availableRole in (IList<IdentityRole>)ViewData["AllRoles"])
   {
       <div class="form-check">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
               name="ViewModel.NewRoles[]"
               value="@availableRole.Name"
               checked="@Model.ViewModel.Roles.Contains(availableRole.Name)">
           <label class="form-check-label">@availableRole</label>
       </div>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but i think my question wasn't clear enough. My whole ViewModel doesn't get it's values and it is generic property of PageModel<T>,  before I've decided to use one generic model for all views it worked like a charm, and after T was added it stopped.

Comment: @Stablo What's your SDK version. My above code is using ASP.NET Core 3.1.00 and it works fine for me (except the Email property( because you didn't render it) and the Id). I could get the Password/Roles/NewRoles correctly

Comment: Just checked and it's .Net core 2.1 for logic project, 2.2 for mvc

Comment: @Stablo Could you please also press `F12` in browser and show us the payload you sent the server?

Comment: Of course, but I'm currently at the computer that doesn't have actual version of project - I haven't pushed it yet. I could do that in about 6 hours if that's not a problem

Comment: @Stablo By the way, if possible, could you please also include the Playload/Error info/ModelState  if my approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: Tnak you very much! :) Fixed with your help, but first I had to find out that disabled tag in form was destroying everything.